# Typhoon - Runtime Configurable Components Using Storyboard

Tags: typhoon

When my application starts I fetch a remote config file containing information (URLs, etc) required to configure other dependencies.

After I fetch the remote config I have a `Config` object that I need to supply to other `TyphoonDefinition`s.

Now I am also using the plist storyboard integration.

I was originally going down the path of injecting the assembly into the ViewController that loads the Config object, and when I receive the remote config and create the Config object, I would somehow set it as a property on the assembly.  I did this hoping that I could then use the property in the definitions, but this did not work and I got:

```
2014-10-22 21:18:06.203 four[39840:516543] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No component matching id 'setConfig:'.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3e63f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a07fbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3e632d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   four                                0x00000001070a011d -[TyphoonComponentFactory componentForKey:args:] + 148
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2de22c __invoking___ + 140
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2de082 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 290
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a36d456 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
    7   four                                0x000000010709d358 -[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory forwardInvocation:] + 276
```

Is there any way for me to inject an object into an assembly at runtime?

Is there a cleaner way to do what I'm trying to do?

I was reading about run-time arguments which sounds like what I need, but I really don't understand the docs.

For example, I have this as a definition.  I need to pass the runtime Config object as a parameter to the constructor.

```
- (id<ApiService>)apiService
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ApiService class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {}];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using runtime arguments**

> For example, I have this as a definition. I need to pass the runtime
>   Config object as a parameter to the constructor.
>
> ```
> - (id<ApiService>)apiService {
> return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ApiService class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {}]; }
> ```

Try something like this:

```
- (id<ApiService>)apiServiceWithConfig:(Config *)config {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ApiService class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {

        // inject into property: 
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(config) with:config];

        // inject into constructor:
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithConfig:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:config];
        }];

    }]; 
}
```

**Using factory definition**

Take a look into next two definitions:

```
- (Config *)currentConfig {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withFactory:[self configManager] selector:@selector(currentConfig)];
}

 - (ConfigManager *)configManager {
     return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ConfigManager class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition){
         definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
     }];
 }
```

Imagine you have a ConfigManager which downloads remote config and stores it as 'currentConfig' property, 'configManager' definition describes that object.

Then check the 'currentConfig' definition. This definition just returns result of calling  'currentConfig'method on ConfigManager instance.

Then you can inject config as:

```
- (id<ApiService>)apiService {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ApiService class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(config) with:[self currentConfig]];
    }]; 
}
```

But make sure that currentConfig loaded (not nil) during 'apiService' creation. (maybe better inject ConfigManager instead - then if currentConfig nil, it would be filled later)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess what I'm not quite grasping with runtime arguments is how do you provide the argument.  Do I inject the assembly, and then call the method to inject the argument?  Also, do you only need to call it once, and then all injections after that will contain the updated dependency?

Comment: This solution does not use runtime arguments. It uses what's called a factory component. Click the themes link in the Readme of this Typhoon sample app: https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon-example

Comment: https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon-example/blob/master/PocketForecast/Assembly/PFThemeAssembly.m

Comment: I was able to get this approach working correctly by injecting the ConfigManager into the apiService.  This is a really awesome DI library.  There's definitely a learning process between the terminology and knowing when to use what, but it is greatly improving my code especially along side some AOP for logging, etc.

Comment: @Steve Sorry I didn't read Aleksey's answer properly. He suggests two solutions. The first *does* use run-time arguments. The 2nd uses a factory component. . glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- Run-time arguments are ***super-cool feature*** and really help to get the full power of Typhoon. We strongly recommend to learn about them (ask questions here, if you like). They're not a good fit for what you're trying to do though.
- It is possible to register a new definition in the container at runtime using:

.

```
- (void)registerDefinition:(TyphoonDefinition *)definition;
```

. . you probably don't want to do this in your case either.

what you *are* interested in is:

**TyphoonComponentFactoryPostProcessor and TyphoonComponentPostProcessor:**

Typhoon has two kinds of interfaces that can be attached, one is [TyphoonComponentFactoryPostProcessor](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/protocol_typhoon_component_factory_post_processor-p.html) and the other is [TyphoonComponentPostProcessor](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/_typhoon_component_post_processor_8h.html). They are used internally, but you can also write your own and do all kinds of cool things with them.

- **TyphoonComponentFactoryPostProcessor:** Modifies the *definitions* (recipes) for a component before it gets built.
- **TyphoonComponentPostProcessor:** Modifies the *instances* after they are built.

**TyphoonConfig:**

There is an existing TyphoonComponentFactoryPostProcessor that you can use for the task you described. Its called [TyphoonConfigPostProcessor](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/interface_typhoon_config_post_processor.html) and is [described in the user guide here](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#typhoon-config).

All post processors can be attached either at built-time (in the assembly), or at runtime, as follows:

```
TyphoonConfigPostProcessor* configurer = [[TyphoonConfigPostProcessor alloc] init];
[configurer useResourceWithName:@"Configuration.plist"]];
[factory attachPostProcessor:configurer];
```

Note that, since TyphoonComponentFactoryPostProcessor modifies ***definitions***, if you have components of singleton scope that are already built, they would not be affected. You'd have to either create lazy singletons, or call `[factory unload]`.

**How do I get a reference to the TyphoonComponentFactory after startup?**

Whichever thing in your app is doing the configuration step will need to be made 'Typhoon Aware'. You can do this by using the following:

```
- (ConfigController *)configController
{
    return [ConfigController withClass:[INFGiftDeliveryAddressController class] 
        configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition)
    {        
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(factory) with:self];
    }];
```

. . when inject the assembly you can declare a property of type `TyphoonComponentFactory` or any of your assembly sub-classes. It will work either way. The documentation for this feature [is here](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself).

In mobile and desktop applications, your components will often need to be made 'Typhoon aware' so they we can proceed from one object graph (eg a view controller) to another (and this is where the run-time arguments feature can be useful). Note that you're coding to your own domain-specific assembly interface, so Typhoon is "non-invasive". For the most part your apps don't refer to any Typhoon APIs directly.

We've covered quite a lot here, so if you have any further questions or need clarifications don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you for the help in understanding.  There are a lot of options here, and I'm not sure I fully grasp the best approach.  Now in my case, I am fetching a remote config, so I will have to wait for an async network operation to complete before I have my object.  In the TyphoonConfigPostProcessor example, you refer to a plist file...I guess I am having a hard time seeing the connection to how I would use this in my case.  Also, why would runtime arguments not be a good fit?

Comment: You're right, I've given you a lot of information (probably too much), but once you understand the foundation features, its easy to put them together and make your own solutions. Still, this is a book's worth info, so let's focus on your specific problem first, and get you going with Aleksey's approach. As for your other two questions: a) What are runtime arguments? Can you post a separate question? b) What is the TyphoonConfig feature and why does it use a plist? Can you likewise post a separate question?